# Database column Varchar Int dilemma

Tags: database, string, insert, int

I have an erd for recipes,

recipe->recipecomponent<-component

If i insert a recipe with ingredients, i would then insert on both recipe and component table then take the ids of both inserted then insert it to the middle table.

so the middle table has 2 col which are Foreign keys to the table and PK to the other 2 tables which are Auto Increment int types.

The problem now is that, when if i insert a recipe with 2 ingredients, since i would insert 2 rows on component which means i need to insert 2 ids from component into recipe component.

For example.

Say, i just inserted a recipe with 2 ingredients,

As i inserted in recipe the id is 1(AI,INT).
since it has 2 ingredients, i insert the 2 in component.
should then have 1(AI,INT) and 2(AI,INT).

i would then have to insert those ids(Which are PK to the 2 tables) as FK to the middle table.

Expected row would be on recipecomponent table is

recipeid - componentid

```
1   ||    1 2
```

How do i insert on component id. Do i insert it with an array?

```
$insert_row = array('recipeid'=>$recipeid,'componentid'=>componentids);
```

Assuming that componentids is an array that contains 1,2 ids from component table.

This is no problem, but when you try to insert this. It will show in the value as ARRAY which gives off an error

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 553

and

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
>
> INSERT INTO `recipecomponent` ( `recipeid`, `componentid`) VALUES ( 1,
>   Array)
>
> Filename: C:\www\KG\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

I found a solution to this though, I converted it to string with implode

```
$new_component_id = implode(' ',$componentid);
```

but then since its now a string "1 2" and when i insert it to the column which is an int type it only shows in the row the first digit which is 1.

I thought about just inserting separately. this would have no problem for a recipe with only 2 ingredients.

would be like this then:

recipeid - componentid

> 1     ||      1
>
> 1     ||      2

but say i inserted a recipe with atleast 4 ingredients and many more to be inserted. Would it be a waste for memory?

If so, I was thinking if there was any character thats considered an integer but is accepted as a value to be inserted like, assume the character -

so when i insert the string 1-2 it would show up as 1-2 on my col which is an int type.

I need some professional help and advice.

Comment: Additional info, 

The last part where i was asking for a character is because i am suspicious that it got cut off with the space character so 2 wasnt included. but then if i cut off the space, i wouldnt be able to determine the id that was inserted. instead of 1 2 ids it would now look like 12. which is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The last option, with one record per ingredient, is the correct way to go. This is what the bridge table "recipecomponent" is for.

Inserting multiple values in the same column (like in your first example) is against [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (again, that's what the bridge table is for). More importantly, when you're querying for a particular id, having the ids on different records is quicker than parsing a string with multiple ids.

What happens with $new_component_id (i.e. the second id is cut off) is probably because of some data type conversion (whether this happens on the database side, or on the PHP side, is not explicit from the problem you're reporting).

If you wish to insert multiple ingredients using only one query, you can use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO recipecomponent (recipeid, componentid) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3);
```